# Как заставить программу работать в фоне после закрытия части с интерфейсом?

Tags: c#, winforms

Сегодня написал свой первый более-менее серьезный проект на C# - тайм менеджер. У меня есть система заметок, которые создаёт пользователь и функция, которая проверяет дату и время с заданными пользователем, а потом вызывает всплывающее окошко с информацией о надвигающемся событии. Подскажите, как можно реализовать работу приложения в фоне? К примеру: человек закрывает всю программу имеющую GUI на крестик, но должен быть процесс работающий в фоне, который будет отсчитывать время и выводить окошко события, а так же не будет виден на приборной панели(завершить его можно только через диспетчер задач или отключением ПК). Как я могу создать нечто подобное? Вопрос, наверное, сложный в реализации, потому буду рад даже малейшей теории и идеям без единой строчки кода

Comment: Приложение не надо закрывать, его надо сворачивать. При сворачивании приложение можно скрыть с панели задач и для того чтобы не потерять управление, добавить иконку в системный трей. То есть по сути, работающее "в фоне" приложение не закрыто, а просто свернуто.

Comment: @aepot у меня была идея написать еще второе приложение, которое будет автоматически запускаться после закрытия главного и естественно будет потреблять мизерное кол-во ОЗУ. Как Вы думаете, есть ли смысл создавать стороннее приложение?

Comment: Вся "сложная реализация" того что вы хотите вот: `this.ShowInTaskBar = false; this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;`

Comment: По-хорошему, если вы стремитесь к правильной реализации, вам нужно создать отдельно проект - [Службу Windows](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/21.1.php) и отдельно проект с приложением, которое ей управляет.

Comment: @aepot Благодарю Вас, сейчас займусь созданием проекта-службы :-)

Comment: Еще как варинт использовать [ApplicationContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2) тогда ваше приложение не будет зависть от закрытия главного окна. По сути приложение может быть вообще без окон

Answer (score 0):

Создай поток с нужной задачей, который будет продолжать работать после закрытия UI

delegate void threadMethod(object obj);

```
    private Thread CreateThread(threadMethod method)
    {
        Thread thread = null;
        try
        {
            if (thread == null)
            {
                // Создать параметрический поток (параметр - потоковая функция)
                ParameterizedThreadStart parameterized = new ParameterizedThreadStart(method);

                // Сосздать поток
                thread = new Thread(parameterized);

                // Закрыть ли поток при закрытии окна
                thread.IsBackground = false;

            //    // Старт потока
                thread.Start();
            }
        }
        catch { }

        return thread;
    }
```

А запараметрировать можно вот так например:

```
       void threadCurrentFunction(object obj)
    {
    while(true)
    {
    //есть что делать
    }
    //по завершению потока, когда то его нужно закрыть
        threadCurrent?.Abort();
        threadCurrent = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть библиотека, вот ссылка https://github.com/Psyxoz13/Native.

все довольно просто, подключите эту библиотеку:

```
using Native.Window;
```

и  вставьте вот этот код:

```
var window = Window.GetFromHandle(Handle);
window.State = WindowState.Hide;
```

и приложение будет работать в фоновом режиме. Библиотека работает с winapi функциями на которых и работают winforms. если что-то не получается значит нужно запустить от имени администратора. В файле манифеста, если его нет - создать, заменить

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
```

на

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
```